# Wireless radio OFF, Wireless Card Enabled

Tags: troubleshooting, device-manager, wireless-adapter

I have a weird issue where my network connection gets disabled somehow.  Device Manager shows the card as being enabled, the network icon shows that I don't have a wireless card.  Rebooting the computer always fixes it.

I've found a way whereby if I restart the WLAN AutoConfig service and then run diagnostics on the wireless network connection that it comes back up.  Diagnostics said that:

> Windows couldn't automatically bind the IP Protocol stack to the network adapter

and Event Viewer shows that the

> WLAN extensibility module has stopped.

The device is a Lenovo ThinkPad x201 with Intel Centrino 6250 AGN.

What I'd like to do is build the solution into a batch file. So far I have:

```
net stop "WLAN Autoconfig"
net start "WLAN Autoconfig"
```

How can I continue to fix this?

Comment: Have you updated the drivers for it? Also, are you wanting to solve the problem or just looking for help with the batch file?

Comment: At the very least, I would like to be able to fix the issue via a batch file when it occurs.  But it would be amazing to be able to do a long term fix for it. 

I don't recall if this particular laptop is entirely up-to-date.  I have about a dozen of them, and it doesn't appear to be a problem with the rest (at least not that I hear of)

Comment: It is possible that it is the hardware itself too. Since you have multiples of the same computer you could try switching the card from a known working one on a rainy day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had many Thinkpads and I've found that sometimes the Lenovo software that manages things like wireless network connections can sometimes conflict with Windows. If you have that stuff installed, try removing it. If you don't have that software or you are still having issues without it, try removing your wireless card from device manager entirely and allow Windows to find it and auto-update/install new drivers.

Comment: Yeah.. One of the tablets developed touchpad issues after updating the drivers for it.....

The issue is infrequent enough that troubleshooting is difficult, but it causes my users to panic when our software starts spewing dozens of network related error messages. 

I'll try making sure everything is entirely updated when tomorrow, and if that doesn't fix it, I'll try uninstalling several of their utilities.